# Error using Apache Giraph

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I am receiving the following error when I run the SimpleOutDegreeCountComputation proogramme in Apache Giraph.  I am using JsonLongDoubleFloatDouble as the input format.

> $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar
>   $GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner
>   org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleOutDegreeCountComputation -vif
>   org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat
>   -vip /user/hduser/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op
>   /user/hduser/output/Simpleout -w 1 Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is
>   deprecated.
>
> 15/05/18 12:56:04 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge input format
>   specified. Ensure your InputFormat does not require one. 15/05/18
>   12:56:04 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge output format
>   specified. Ensure your OutputFormat does not require one. Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: checkClassTypes: vertex
>   value types not assignable, computation - class
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, VertexInputFormat - class
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable   at
>   org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphConfigurationValidator.checkAssignable(GiraphConfigurationValidator.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphConfigurationValidator.verifyVertexInputFormatGenericTypes(GiraphConfigurationValidator.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphConfigurationValidator.validateConfiguration(GiraphConfigurationValidator.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.giraph.utils.ConfigurationUtils.parseArgs(ConfigurationUtils.java:222)
>     at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:74)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)     at
>   org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:124)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
>   ^[[Ahduser@deepa-Inspiron-N5050:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$
>   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop
>   jGIRAPH_HOME/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner
>   org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleOutDegreeCountComputation -vif
>   org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat
>   -vip /user/hduser/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op
>   /user/hduser/output/Simpleout -w 1

Answer (score 1):

as the logs says your computation e.g. SimpleOutDegreeCountComputation needs LongWritable format for vertex`s id while your data in hdfs is DoubleWritable. So, have two choices: changing SimpleOutDegreeCountComputation to work with DoubleWritable or convert your data from DoubleWritable into LongWritable.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the following reason.
SimpleOutDegreeCountComputation has following signature-

```
public class SimpleOutDegreeCountComputation extends 
BasicComputation<LongWritable, LongWritable, DoubleWritable, DoubleWritable{
//Logic for out degree
}
```

Here, the BasicComputation asks for

```
>1. Long Vertex ID 
>2. Long Vertex Value
>3. Double Edge weight
>4. Double message type
```

You are trying to use JsonLongDoubleFloatDouble format for input. Which give you

```
>1. Long Vertex ID
>2. Double Vertex Value
>3. Float Edge Weight
>4. Double message type
```

Change the BasicComputation signature in the program accordingly.